# Abi calldata encoding nested structs, find a way

Tags: solidity, struct, abi

I didn't found any instructions about nested structs (in structs).
Seen video about sending bytecode to contract and I wanted to understand.

For example, method is:

```
function fulfillOrder(
    Order calldata order,
    bytes32 fulfillerConduitKey
) external payable returns (bool fulfilled);

struct Order {
    OrderParameters parameters;
    bytes signature;
}

struct OrderParameters {
    address offerer; // 0x00
    address zone; // 0x20
    OfferItem[] offer; // 0x40
    ConsiderationItem[] consideration; // 0x60
    OrderType orderType; // 0x80
    uint256 startTime; // 0xa0
    uint256 endTime; // 0xc0
    bytes32 zoneHash; // 0xe0
    uint256 salt; // 0x100
    bytes32 conduitKey; // 0x120
    uint256 totalOriginalConsiderationItems; // 0x140
    // offer.length                          // 0x160
}

struct OfferItem {
    ItemType itemType;
    address token;
    uint256 identifierOrCriteria;
    uint256 startAmount;
    uint256 endAmount;
}

struct ConsiderationItem {
    ItemType itemType;
    address token;
    uint256 identifierOrCriteria;
    uint256 startAmount;
    uint256 endAmount;
    address payable recipient;
}

enum OrderType {
    FULL_OPEN,
    PARTIAL_OPEN,
    FULL_RESTRICTED,
    PARTIAL_RESTRICTED,
    CONTRACT
}
```

```
fulfillOrder(((address,address,(uint8,address,uint256,uint256,uint256)[],(uint8,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,address)[],uint8,uint256,uint256,bytes32,uint256,bytes32,uint256),bytes),bytes32)
```

keccak256 is **b3a34c4c89989a0871b97285782de68e7db27f7d5fe738e7aa7c6f1f7118d3ac**

What is code?:

```
0xb3a34c4c
0x00000...
0x00.. - how represent struct in arguments with nested struct in parent argument struct?
0x0000...
```

I've google a lot, it's didn't gave any results...

That is my analysis, I tried to understand but I don't.

```
0xb3a34c4c
32/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040 .*args[0] 32*2       >-- Order
64/0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000 'fulfillerConduitKey   |
96/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040 'args[0] *Order[0]    <-    >--
128/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280'-------->32*20 link SIG      | OrderParams
160/000000000000000000000000047a0ba6eab7825a854049eda6256301cf0a7056' offerer Order[0] Start cnt <-
192/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' zone
224/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160'- *arr1 352 32*11 *OfferItem[]
256/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000220'- 544 32*17
288/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'  orderType
320/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' FULL_OPEN OrderType - start static
352/000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006383abd0' start time //1669573584
384/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063ab38d0' end time //1672165584
416/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' zoneHash
448/360c6ebe0000000000000000000000000000000000000000f69d6dec7287d948' salt
480/0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000' conduitKey
512/000000000000000000000000b4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6'* arr1 weth
544/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'* identifierOrCriteria
576/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000'* start amount of weth 1*10^19
608/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000'* end amount
640/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' 20th
672/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041 --- SIG length
704/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ---
736/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   } SIG value
768/xx00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ---
```

Maybe code is outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. One rule for tuples - tuple has it own offset start, from first element (itself or offset for) of tuple. And offset in tuples counted from first tuple record including.

Well explained with examples here: https://blog.soliditylang.org/2022/08/08/calldata-tuple-reencoding-head-overflow-bug/ - it helped me.

And bytecode above was also wrong. Right code with my marks see below:

```
  0xb3a34c4c
  32/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040  *args[0] 32*2       >-- Order
  64/0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000  fulfillerConduitKey   |
  96/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040  args[0] *Order[0]    <-    >--
  128/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280 -------->32*20 link SIG      |  OrderParams
  160/000000000000000000000000047a0ba6eab7825a854049eda6256301cf0a7056  offerer Order[0] Start cnt <-
  192/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  zone
  224/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160 - *arr1 352 32*11 *OfferItem[]
  256/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000220 - *arr2 544 32*17 *ConsiderationItem[]
  288/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  FULL_OPEN OrderType - start static
  320/000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006383abd0  startTime //1669573584
  352/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063ab38d0  endTime //1672165584
  384/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  zoneHash
  416/360c6ebe0000000000000000000000000000000000000000f69d6dec7287d948  salt
  448/0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000  conduitKey
  480/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  totalOriginalConsiderationItems
  512/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 ->arr1.length
  544/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 ->arr1.itemType
  576/000000000000000000000000b4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6 ->arr1.wethAddress (token)
  608/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ->arr1.identifierOrCriteria
  640/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000 ->arr1.startAmount of weth 1*10^19
  672/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000 ->arr1.endAmount
  704/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 => arr2.length (0)
  736/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041 --- SIG length
  768/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ---
  800/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   } SIG value
  832/xx00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ---
```

Maybe this will help somebody.